# Typing effect after button press

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to create a button, and when it is pressed it will 'type' out some random text. I've followed many tutorials/code snippets with no luck in getting the implementation right.

Essentially, I want to combine these two scripts. When I click a button it should choose a random string and then use the 'typing' effect to type it.

Pressing the button again will interrupt whatever is being typed, and generate new text.

Any help is really appreciated!

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {

  if (i < txt.length) {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```html
            <button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

            <p id="demo"></p>
```

and this:

```js
        var quotes = [
        'The sky is blue',
            'The stove is hot',
            'The floor is wet',
            'The grass is green',
            'The water is cold'
        ]

        function newQuote() {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
            document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
        }
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay"></div>

    <button onclick="newQuote()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost there

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = ''; //the typing text
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {

  //clear the html initially for a text
  if (i === 0)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';

  if (i < txt.length) {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}


var quotes = [
  'The sky is blue',
  'The stove is hot',
  'The floor is wet',
  'The grass is green',
  'The water is cold'
]

function newQuote() {
  //set the typing text
  txt = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  
  //reset the index
  i = 0;
  typeWriter();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newQuote()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Azad! The comments make it really clear about how to implement both functions! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```js
var i = 0;
var speed = 50;
var timeoutId;
var quotes = [
  'The sky is blue',
  'The stove is hot',
  'The floor is wet',
  'The grass is green',
  'The water is cold'
]

function newQuote() {
  document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerHTML = ""
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *(quotes.length));
  txt = quotes[randomNumber];
  if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  i = 0;
  typeWriter(txt)
}
        
function typeWriter(txt) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, txt);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay"></div>

<button onclick="newQuote()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was after! I kind of knew I'd need two functions but had no idea how to implement both. That's quite clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval` instead:

```js
/* js/external.js */
//<![CDATA[
var doc, bod, I, TypeMaker; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
TypeMaker = function(element, interval){
  this.element = element; this.interval = interval || 50;
  var t = this, r;
  this.type = function(string){
    if(r)clearInterval(r);
    var s = string.split(''), l = s.length, i = 0;
    var p = 'value' in this.element ? 'value' : 'innerHTML';
    this.element[p] = '';
    r = setInterval(function(){
      t.element[p] += s[i++];
      if(i === l){
        clearInterval(r); r = undefined;
      }
    }, t.interval);
  }
}
var typer = new TypeMaker(I('output')), single_test = I('single_test'), rand_test = I('rand_test');
var testArray = ['The sky is blue.', 'The stove is hot.', 'The floor is wet.', 'The grass is green.', 'The water is cold.'];
var testArrayL = testArray.length;
single_test.onclick = function(){
  typer.type('Lorem ipsum dummy text.');
}
rand_test.onclick = function(){
  typer.type(testArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*testArrayL)]);
}
});
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
input{
  padding:3px 5px;
}
#output{
  display:inline-block; margin-left:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <input id='single_test' type='button' value='test' />
  <input id='rand_test' type='button' value='random' />
  <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        let i = 0;
        let randomNumber;
        let speed = 50;
        let clickBtn = document.querySelector("#click");
        let quotes = [
          "The sky is blue",
          "The stove is hot",
          "The floor is wet",
          "The grass is green",
          "The water is cold"
        ];

        const typeWriter = () => {
          if (i === 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
          }
          if (i < quotes[randomNumber].length) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += quotes[randomNumber].charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
          }
        };

        clickBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
          i = 0
          randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
          typeWriter();
        });
```